# Custom phases for a multi-module maven project

Tags: maven-3, multi-module

I am currently working on a multi-module project with the following structure.

```
root
  -module A
  -module B
```

What I want to do is to execute module B (The main method of the module) after the compiling of module B (Module B depends on module A). But I need to do this with a customized command.

Ex -

```
mvn runb
```

I know that the **exec maven plugin** can be used to run a project using maven. What I don't understand is how to create a custom command (phase) in maven. Is there anyway to achieve this without writing a maven plugin?

I referred various guides such as https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLifecycleInMaven trying to achieve this. But they need to create **components.xml** and **lifecycle.xml** files under src/resources/META-INF. I don't understand how to apply that file structure to my project since it is a multi-module project where each module has seperate **src** directories.

(I'm using maven 3)

Comment: It sounds like integration testing what you need which exist in Maven. There exist pre-integration-test life cylce phase and integration-test life-cycle-phase so you can bound the exec plugin to that phase and run **mvn verify**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create a custom lifecycle without writing a Maven plugin.

And without hacking Maven itself, at least as of Maven 3.0.5, it is not possible to add a *custom phase* to Maven through a plugin.  The phases are loaded up by the core of Maven from its configuration before any plugins are processed.

If you really have your heart set on using one command to do what you want, writing a plugin is the only way.  With some [pluginGroup mappings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups) in your `settings.xml`, this can be made simpler (you can specify `mvn my:plugin` rather than `mvn com.mygroupid:plugin`).

But if you are willing to have a slightly more verbose syntax on the command line, what you want could be achieved through profiles and the [exec maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

---

Add a profile to module B that uses the exec plugin to run itself.

Something like this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <profiles>
        <!-- This profile uses local webapp security instead of the BlueCoat device, useful for testing -->
        <profile>
            <id>execb</id>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>runb</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>verify</phase> <!-- Anything after package phase -->
                                <configuration>
                                    <!-- Exec plugin configuration goes here -->
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

You'll need to configure the exec plugin depending on how you run your JAR, more info [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html).

What this does is run the exec plugin as part of module B's build, but only if the `execb` profile is activated.

---

Now, when you just want to build your project (without any exec), build like normal (e.g. `mvn install`).

When you want to build and run, use the command line:

```
mvn install -Pexecb
```

and it will do the exec as part of the build.